# UIPageViewController as a dynamic scrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller

I have been trying to find a layout solution that pages all kinds of views in and out of a scrollView as I scroll. The issue I have is dynamically adding anything to a scrollView causes terrible judder and performance issues. I have always been impressed with how UIPageViewcontroller smoothly moves from one controllers view to another with it's internal caching. 
   Is there a way to achieve this smooth dynamic adding and removal of views on a scrollView? ideally if I could remove the 'snap to page' effect and just have ordinary scrolling on a UIPageController, I could just create 'virtual pages' of content that I would be able to smoothly scroll along.

not sure of this is possible though.

Comment: Have you tried using a collection view?  Making each cell the screen height, or however big your views are will give it a paging effect.  Managing pages through a datasource would be much easier as well.

Comment: The reason a `UIPageViewController` seems to scroll smoothly is because it handles the "pre-loading" of the next "page". If you try to flip quickly ahead through pages, or if you could remove the 'snap to page' effect, it will have essentially the same performance issues. You either need to design your own pre-loading and caching methods for a non-paged scroll view, or design your "pages" to lazy-load / async-load their content.

Comment: yes I suspected that, the scroll performance seems a factor of the number of views to render and the opacity of those view as well. I might try and use a pageViewController to see if it is a good alternative to 'smooth scrolling'.